# ASC DESC in Sorting Table

Tags: php, html, function, sorting

I'm very new to this but my project have to create a table that can sort by clicking

I found this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

And I'm already try it but got some problem here :

My table got 4 Headers : Name (Varchar) Number (Varchar) Type (Varchar) Price (INT)

In the first 3 headers it works fine with the click and it goes ASC > DESC or DESC > ASC .

The Problem is the last one Price (INT) it goes like 1 10 11 12 2 3 4 40 5

I have look in to it for like a day and i can't solve it by my self :(

so can anyone here help me or guide me what i've missed?

EDIT : My Code

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */T
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  echo "<table id='myTable' border='0' width='570px' align='center'>
        <tr>
        <th onclick='sortTable(0)'> Number </th>
        <th onclick='sortTable(1)'> Name </th>
        <th onclick='sortTable(2)'> Type </th>
        <th onclick='sortTable(3)'> Price </th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr class='item'>";
          echo "<td>".$row['ProductNumber']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['ProductName']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['TypeName']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['ProductPrice']."</td>";
          }
      echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to share to code that does the number sorting, otherwise we can't help much

Comment: ok ill try share it now

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that you are sorting the integers as string values instead of as an integer value. (This would explain why they are being sorted in the fashion you see: 1 10 11 12 2 3 4 40 5) To ensure that the sort is sorting the numbers as integers instead of the string value of those numbers cast the column as a list of integers or cast each element as an integer.
You are going to need to make another method or add to your current method a way to sort numbers as integers. so instead of calling the same sort call a SortInt only on the last column. This should sort the numbers correctly.

Change the if statement in the new sort function.
From:

```
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())
```

to:

```
if (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) > parseInt(y.innerHTML, 10))
if (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) < parseInt(y.innerHTML, 10))
```

Comment: still cant fix it :(

Comment: try parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: only do this on the last column so you will need another function for this sort the only differences should be on these lines                                               "if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())" to            
"if (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) > parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10))" in both places this line shows up. Hope this helps.

Comment: if (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) > parseInt(y.innerHTML, 10))

Comment: OMG it works i forgot to change the "> and <" i used "> and >"  THX !